# Darcs dependency tree view

Tags: graphics, dependencies, darcs

Is there a tool that can show a tree view representing patches dependencies in darcs? I found [DarcsDeps](http://darcs.net/RelatedSoftware/DarcsDeps) but it seems dead and I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the tool you found, no. Your best bet may be to continue to try to get it to work.